# iOS keyboard keep focused on form input after the page on iframe is redirected

Tags: javascript, html, ios, iframe, safari

There is an iframe in a page, I noticed that on iOS after submitting a text to an search input the keyboard does not disappear after the page is reloaded and it becomes impossible to select anything inside or outside the iframe.
Here is an example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/ios-keyboard-68rcq6
Or directly open the example app here: https://68rcq6.csb.app/

Note that by pressing keyboard's search button does not break the page if the input is outside of the iframe.

I have tried to call `blur` on every `onload` of the iframe and also calling `focus` on other elements has no effect, neither the keyboard closes nor the selection is possible.